# column template kendo ui grid mvc action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

The following code is working fine in development, as soon as i deploy in web server it said could find file directory. I need to change the .client template so its not hard coded like before. So if we deploy to the server where the Top folder name different or the hierarchy change, it still find the page.

I was thinking using @Url.Action but not sure how in this case to implement in .CLientTemplate

```
columns.Template(@<text>
           @Html.ActionLink(@item.FirstName, "Index", "Summary", new { testId = @item.FirstName })  
         </text>)
          .ClientTemplate("<a href='/Summary/Index/?testId =#= TestId #'>#=FirstName#</a>").Title("First Name");
```

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should do:

```
.ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("Index", "Summary", new { testId = "#=TestId#" }) + "'>#=FirstName#</a>")
```

Answer (score 6):

I got this one working fine

```
columns.Bound(a => a.Id)
       .Title("Action")
       .Filterable(false)
       .ClientTemplate(
                       "<a href='" 
                      + Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller") 
                      + "/#= Id #'" 
                      + ">View</a>"
                      );
```

I needed an extra column and a link button field for go to details page of a customer. I don't need filter option for this column and that is why I remove it using `Filterable(false)`. Also you can give the link content and column header as above. This value `"/#= Id #'"` is the one I pass to the controller action method.

Answer (score 3):

In case you're using server-binding (as opposed to ajax) and Razor as your view-engine, here is an example.  I need a link such as /Controller/Action/Id where Id is obtained from a property of the model.  Please note that @item denotes the model instance being currently processed by the grid.

```
columns.Template(@<text>@Html.ActionLink(AbaScore.Resources.App.Edit,"ACTION", "CONTROLLER", new { @item.Id }, null)</text>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen 87 different examples of this and none of them worked. This is what I finally did and it worked, and it's simple as heck.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.member_id)
       .ClientTemplate("<a href='/members/details/#=member_id#'>Details</a>")
       ;
```